# Excel formula to sum values based on reference number in another column

Tags: excel-formula

I have two columns. One is an amount and the other is a reference number. I need a formula to sum all amounts per reference number next to the reference number in order to sort from highest to lowest value per reference.

```
Amount | Reference | Sum per Reference
122.00 |   405221  |     316
194.00 |   405221  |     316
339.80 |   405682  |     851.25
296.45 |   405682  |     851.25
215.00 |   405682  |     851.25
```

The closest formula I found on this website, was:

```
=IF((AR2=AR3),"",SUM($AQ2:AQ2-SUM(AV$1:AV1)))
```

This however only puts the sum value (like a subtotal) at the last reference number and leaves the other ones blank. I need it to put the sum value for each reference number next to all the lines and have not blank spaces?

Comment: Can you provide some sample of your data with desired output?

Comment: uhm - not sure how I can attach a file?

Comment: You can't attach files, but you can format your table using code blocks and spaces, or if that doesn't work for you, include a screenshot.

Comment: AMOUNT       REFERENCE  SUM per Reference 
 122.00         405221         316.00
 194.00         405221         316.00 
 9 339.80         405682         11 296.45 
 1 741.65         405682         11 296.45 
 215.00         405682         11 296.45

Comment: I give up - screenshots not pasting - spaces not working, no idea what code blocks is.. #tech-challenged

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is the `SUMIF` function. It sums values by a criterion, so in this case we can use it to sum all values that match another value. Assuming your values are in Column A and your criteria are in Column B:

`=SUMIF($B:$B,$B2,$A:$A)` Put this formula in your "SUM per Reference" column and copy it down, and you should get a good result.

Comment: Thanks so much. Just tried this, but all results were zero instead of adding up all the amounts with the same reference number.